# ActionController::RoutingError: No route matches [PUT] rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I have some problem with my test.

There is my **profile_pages_spec.rb**:

```
describe "ProfilePages" do

subject { page }

describe "edit" do
  let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
  let(:profile) do
    FactoryGirl.create(:profile, user: user)
  end
before do
  login user
  visit edit_profile_path(profile)
end

it { should have_selector('h2', text: 'Заполните информацию о себе') }

describe "change information" do
  let(:new_city)  { "Ulan-Bator" }
  let(:new_phone) { 1232442 }
  let(:new_gamelevel) { "M2" }
  let(:new_aboutme)   { "nfsfsdfds" }
  let(:submit) { "Сохранить" }
  before do
    fill_in "Город",             with: new_city
    fill_in "Телефон",           with: new_phone
    select new_gamelevel,        from: "Уровень игры"
    fill_in "О себе",            with: new_aboutme
    click_button submit
  end
  specify { profile.reload.city.should  == new_city }
  specify { profile.reload.phone.should == new_phone }
  specify { profile.reload.gamelevel.should == new_gamelevel }
  specify { profile.reload.aboutme.should == new_aboutme }
end
describe "submitting to the update action" do
  before { put edit_profile_path(profile) }
  specify { response.should redirect_to(user_path(user)) }
end
end
end
```

There is my **profiles_controller.rb**:

```
  def edit
    @profile = current_user.profile
  end

  def update
    @profile = current_user.profile
  if @profile.update_attributes(params[:profile])
    flash[:success] = "Профиль обновлен!"
    redirect_to user_path(current_user)
  else
    render 'edit'
  end
 end
```

profile form:

```
        <%= form_for(@profile) do |f| %>  

    <%= render 'devise/shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>

      <div><%= f.label :city, "Город" %>
      <%= f.text_field :city, :autofocus => true %></div>

      <div><%= f.label :phone, "Телефон" %>
      <%= f.number_field :phone %></div>

      <div><%= f.label :gamelevel, "Уровень игры" %>
      <%= f.select(:gamelevel,[['Pro', 'Pro'],
                               ['M1', 'M1'], 
                               ['M2', 'M2'],
                               ['M3', 'M3']])  %></div>

      <div><%= f.label :aboutme,"О себе" %>

      <%= f.text_area :aboutme, placeholder: "Немного о себе...",size: "              40x10"     %></div>

      <div><%= f.submit "Сохранить", class: "btn  btn-primary" %></div>
    <% end %>
```

In firefox I can sent my form and data will change. But in my spec I have error:

ActionController::RoutingError: No route matches [PUT]

rake routes:

edit_profile GET    /profiles/:id/edit(.:format)   profiles#edit

profile PUT    /profiles/:id(.:format)        profiles#update

I don't understand what I did wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the PUT HTTP request must be done on the profile_path and not on the edit_profile_path as you did. The edit_profile_path works with GET request and displays the edit profile form. It does not actually update the profile...

Try

```
  before { put profile_path(profile) }
```

Comment: It's works. But another error: Failure/Error: specify { response.should redirect_to(user_path(user)) }
       Expected response to be a redirect to <http://www.example.com/users/1> but was a redirect to <http://www.example.com/users/sign_in>  I think it's something wrong with devise helpers.